# как работает деструктор С++?

Tags: c++, деструктор

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться, написал метод для очистки бин.дерева. Если метод вызвать в функции main, то все нормально работает, а если вызвать этот метод в деструкторе, то ошибка: g++ зацикливается в месте else if(temp->left != nullptr){...}, а VS пишет ошибка доступа. Вот код, add добавляет элемент, clear удаляет все узлы:

```
struct node
{
    std::string numberAuto;
    std::list<std::string> offense;
    node *left, *right, *parent;
};

void BinaryTree::clear()
{   
    node* temp = this->root;
    node* t{nullptr};
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        t = temp->parent;
        if(temp->left == nullptr && temp->right == nullptr)
        {
            if(temp == this->root)
            {
                delete temp;
                this->root = nullptr;
                break;
            }
            if(temp == t->left)
                t->left = nullptr;
            else t->right = nullptr;
            delete temp;
            temp = t;           
        }
        else if(temp->right != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->right;
        }
        else if(temp->left != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->left;
        }
    }
}

BinaryTree BinaryTree::add(std::string number_auto, 
                           std::string offense
                           )
{
    // если дерево пусто
    if (this->root == nullptr)
    {
        this->root = new node{};
        this->root->numberAuto = number_auto;
        this->root->offense.push_back(offense);
        this->root->left = nullptr;
        this->root->right = nullptr;
        this->root->parent = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        // если в дереве уже имеются узлы
        node* temp = this->root;
        node* y = nullptr;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            // сравнение проводим по номеру авто
            // если меньше идем влево, если больше вправо
            y = temp;
            if (number_auto < temp->numberAuto)
                temp = temp->left;
            else if (number_auto > temp->numberAuto)
                temp = temp->right;
            else 
            {
                // если авто с таким номером уже существует в дереве
                // то добавляем нарушение в его список правонарушений
                temp->offense.push_back(offense);
                return *this;
            }
         }

        // если такого номера в дереве нет
        // то создаем новый узел
        temp = new node{};
        // добавляем номер и нарушение в узел
        temp->numberAuto = number_auto;
        temp->offense.push_back(offense);
        temp->left = nullptr;
        temp->right = nullptr;

        // указываем родителя
        temp->parent = y;
        // если номер больше то добавляем вправо от родителя
        // иначе влево
        if (temp->numberAuto > y->numberAuto)
            y->right = temp;
        else
        {
            y->left = temp;
        }
    }
      // возвращаем сам объект
     return *this;
}

BinaryTree::~BinaryTree()
{
    this->clear();
}
```

Comment: Чёт слишком сложно. В деструкторе node можно обойтись буквально парой строк)

Comment: Это бинарное дерево. Он добирается до листьев и удаление происходит снизу вверх. Парой строк навряд ли

Comment: Вы забыли 2  вещи. 1) написать, что именно происходит при ошибке. 2) привести код класса и в частности, деструктора (с вызовом `clear()` и без него (это когда `clear()` вызывается из main и работает))

Comment: g++ зацикливается в месте else if(temp->left != nullptr){...}, а VS пишет ошибка доступа

Comment: Скорее всего, неприятности из-за того, что когда вызов в деструкторе, при каждом `delete temp` вызывается деструктор, который опять вызывает `clear`...

Comment: Если все закомментировать в clear() и просто вывести узлы внутри clear, то когда вызывается деструктор, он выводит segmentation fault, а если посмотреть на узлы внутри какого-то другого метода, то все нормально выводиться

Comment: Приведите код деструктора. Скорее всего у вас где-то есть повторный вызов удаления для уже удаленного объекта.

Comment: Деструктор просто вызывает clear 
BinaryTree::~BinaryTree()
{
    this->clear();
}

Comment: `Парой строк навряд ли` `delete left; delete right; left=right=null;`

Answer (score 4):

Вы возвращаете копию дерева в `BinaryTree BinaryTree::add(){..}`.
И не написали главные функции копирования/перемещения и присвоения. В деструкторе временного дерева вся память удаляется и всё падает. Сначала исправьте возвращаемое значения на ссылку
`BinaryTree & BinaryTree::add(){ .. return * this ; }`

И потом уже допишите главные функции

```
BinaryTree(BinaryTree const &);
BinaryTree(BinaryTree &&);
BinaryTree & operator =(BinaryTree const &);
BinaryTree & operator =(BinaryTree &&);
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо большое